# Direct representation of simplical complexes in a HoTT implementation

Tags: computational-topology, persistent-homology

Persistent homology can be used to transform a point-cloud into a simplical complex.

Do such simplical complexes have a first-class representation:

1. Conceptually, within HoTT?
2. Concretely, within some existing programming language (e.g. Agda)?

Comment: You can certainly represent a simplicial complex in HoTT or in Agda in essentially the same way you can in ZFC or in C. So, I think this isn't your real question. Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289711/defining-sun-in-hott