# Solving the sextic equation using univariate analytic functions and arithmetic operations

Tags: polynomials, hypergeometric-functions

Inspired by the top answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233483/what-advantage-humans-have-over-computers-in-mathematics), I would like to push the limit of the [Hermite-Brioschi-Kronecker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#cite_ref-8). Suppose we only allow solutions to be expressed in terms of basic arithmetic operations in the complex field and a universal collection of finite number of ***univariate*** meromorphic functions $\mathfrak{F}_6$. Is the sextic equation still unsolvable?

If we allow some element of $\mathfrak{F}_6$ to be bivariate (for instance the [Lauricella functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23094/method-of-finding-roots-of-polynominal-equations-with-arithmetic-operations-and)), then an arbitrary sextic equation becomes solvable, since one can bring polynomial equations to the [Bring-Jerrard normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form). More generally what's the lowest maximum valency of $\mathfrak{F}_n$ possible for general $n$-th degree polynomial equations? I conjecture it's $n-4$, i.e., the trivial upper bound. Is that correct?

Comment: This is an old question, but a comment might be useful. One can use a Tschirnhausen transformation ***in radicals***  to eliminate the $x^{n-1}, x^{n-2}, x^{n-3}$ terms of the general equation of deg $n\geq4$. For $n=6$, this leaves us with $$x^6+x^2+ax+b = 0$$ but this is qualitatively different from the quintic version which doesn't have the $x^2$ term. For $n=6$, if we wish to get rid of the $x^{n-4}$ term as well, then the required Tschirnhausen transformation is no longer in radicals.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Out of curiosity, if we remove the $x^{6-4}=x^2$ term, would one need a quintic Tschirnhausen transformation or which type? Thanks

Comment: @TymaGaidash Remove 4 terms from the sextic, including the $x^2$ term? A deg-4 Tschirnhaus transformation would suffice, but its coefficients will be deg $4!=24$ so it wont be in radicals.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I just remembered. There is a special quintic Tschirnhausen transformation for the general sextic, but its function is to knock off the three odd terms $(x^5, x^3, x)$ so it becomes the "cubic" $y^6+Ay^4+By^2+C$. The strange thing is one needs to solve another sextic to do this. (A version of this sextic resolvent was known to Hilbert and Joubert.) I'll make a question about it in MSE or MO soon.